# Is "Unix & Linux" the best forum for this issue?

Tags: support

I have a problem with my computer (Ubuntu), but I don't know if this is the best forum for that, because I don't know if this is a tecnichal problem, or a problem of ubuntu, or a problem little specific. I have other doubts about, in this case, could i repost it in other forums? What is the exact forum for this case?

**This is the issue:  [Constantly I have to use `fsck` to fix my PC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/576627/329018)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question seems fine to me. It is on topic here and welcome to stay. It would also be on topic on other SE sites<sup>*</sup>, like [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) or [Super User](https://superuser.com), but if you want to post it there, please delete the one you posted here first.

In general, we handle pretty much any problem that relates to using a *nix (including Linux) machine. So your question is welcome here.

---

<sup>*</sup>  <sub>Note that these sites are not forums, but question and answer sites. They don't work like forums, we have no discussion, and some people really hate it if you call them forums.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, they are not forums, I will be more careful with my language.